# JavaScript - A long array with UNIX timestamps. How to get from the latest 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a array with many UNIX timestamps and want for example get the timestamps, which are from the last e.g. 10 minutes.

To be more precise I only need the count, likely for a Bot protection.

Should I do it with a for loop and check if the UNIX timestamp + 600 is smaller than the current timestamp? Or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Are the timestamps in the array ordered?

Comment: related - [What's the best way to query an array in javascript to get just the items from it I want?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257786/whats-the-best-way-to-query-an-array-in-javascript-to-get-just-the-items-from-i)

Comment: They are ordered yes.

Comment: If you downvote, please tell me why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Array filter, e.g

```
var now = Date.now();
var times = [now-10000, now-50, now-300, now-700, now];

var tenMinutesAgo = Date.now()-600;
var passed = times.filter(function(v){return v > tenMinutesAgo});

console.log(passed.length); // 3
```