# Angular JS: how to "load" an individual record from a json dataset?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, state

I have json data, an array of 50 objects representing people. Each one has parameters like `id` and `lastName`.

I load this into my controller via a resolve, `EmployeeResolve`, and into a variable `_this.employees`

I also load via $state params from a previous page a `rowNumber` variable that holds the ID of the record the user clicked on: `_this.rowNum = $stateParams.id;`let's say the `id` is `5`.

I would like to assign to a variable now the object number 5 (for want of a better way of explaining) so that in my HTML  I can bind to it as in `{{controller.lastName}}`

What's the syntax for getting the 5th item out of `employees`?

**UPDATE**
After several helpful comments and answers, I've gotten this far (people are now packages):

```
_this.recordNum = Number($stateParams.id);
  _this.packages = PackagesResolve;

  _this.currentPackage = _this.packages.filter(function(pkg) {
    return pkg.id === _this.recordNum;
  });

  $log.debug('package from filter', _this.currentPackage[0].status);
```

Note though, I expected after all this for `_this.currentPackage` to contain an object, so I could simply bind to its props in the html as in `currentPackage.last_name`  But it does not.  It's a *resource* and I need to use the above `_this.currentPackage[0].status` in the log statement to get anything.  And that's not going to allow binding.

A colleague suggested modifying my resolve as such

```
PackagesResolve: function($log, MockDataFactory) {
      return MockDataFactory.query({filename: 'packages'}).$promise.then(function(response) {
        return response;
      });
    }
```

Adding the whole `$promise.then` part.  No real difference.

To reiterate what I am trying to do:

PackagesResolve is getting a json array of 50 objects.  I want to be able to get the CURRENT object when its row in a table of that json is clicked.

And no, @jdvp it's not a duplicate of that other post at all.  I need to do this with Angular, not jquery or straight js.

Comment: `var fifthEmployee = _this.employees[5];`?? It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: You could apply a filter on the array:  `var fifthEmployee = _this.employees.filter(function(employee){ return (employee.id == 5)})`. From what I'm getting form your story it's a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257786/whats-the-best-way-to-query-an-array-in-javascript-to-get-just-the-items-from-i

Comment: not quite, that's why I am confused.  `var fifthEmployee = _this.employees[5];`    However it I try to substitute the passed index, it fails.   `var fifthEmployee = _this.employees[_this.rowNum];` does not work

Comment: I've used your filter function idea, but for some reason I need to do this afterwards to log the value of "status" (one of the props in the object):  `$log.debug('package from filter', _this.currentPackage[0].status);`  I modified the question.

Comment: Incidentally, I realized why `_this.employees[_this.rowNum]` does not work, of course JS converted the number to a string.

Comment: what does `Number($stateParams.id);` do? it seems like that is where the `rowNum` gets mangled;  if your `rowNum` is a number, then `_this.Employees[_this.rowNum]` would work;  your other solution with filters *somewhat works*, but it doesn't return the element, it returns an array with one element holding the filtered value.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly: the object returned by resolve is the resolved promise. The "data" of the resolved promise, which in this case would be the expected array of people info, is stored inside `resolve.data`. So for e.g. you have `EmployeeResolve`, you can reference the array and store it using:

Editing based on comments:

```
// Assuming you've done all error checking...
_this.employees = EmployeeResolve.data;

// Now _this.employees has the array of people info.

$scope.controller = {};
$scope.controller.variableName = _this.employees[$stateParams.id];
// Now, you can access your object in your template using controller.variableName.
```

Now although I wouldn't recommend writing code like that in your final version, I'm sure you get the gist. ;)

Additional notes: The reason I'm creating an empty object and storing it as `controller` on the scope is because your question stated it. I am assuming you have your own reasons for wanting to namespace your variable inside of `controller`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not going to work, since I'd need a variable defined for everything on my page.  I was looking to get the whole object assigned to a variable so I can simply do `{{controller.myvariable.last_name}}` in the html

Comment: the syntax of `{{controller.variablename}}` that is used is probably referring to the ControllerAs syntax.