# remove an array from an array using the inner arrays first item with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to remove a specific array from an array using the first items name.

For example:

```
myArray = [["human", "mammal"], ["shark", "fish"]];
```

I need to use the first item in this array to remove the array containing it.

Let's say I want to remove the array containing `['human', 'mammal']`.
How would I remove it using the first value `'human'` in that array?

Before I had a two dimensional array I was able to remove the specific item from the array using this code:

```
var removeItem = productArray.indexOf(valueLabel);
if (removeItem != -1) {
    productArray.splice(removeItem, 1);
}
```

Obviously this method will not work anymore.

Comment: The answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257786/whats-the-best-way-to-query-an-array-in-javascript-to-get-just-the-items-from-i looks like what you want. Namely `var wanted = items.filter( function(item){return (item.age==18);} );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is not even required for this task. **[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will be able to solve this problem**:

```js
var myArray = [["human", "mammal"], ["shark", "fish"]];
var exclude = "human";

var filtered = myArray.filter(function(item) {
  return item[0] !== exclude;
});

console.log(filtered); // [["shark", "fish"]]
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was going for.