# how to extract the JSON schema (sub schema) of a property from complete object json schema

Tags: json, node.js, schema, json-schema-validator

I need a help regarding schema extraction by property.

For example i have a JSON schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "A simple address format",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "street-name": { "type": "string" },
        "locality":{ "type": "string" },
        "region": { "type": "string" },
        "postal-code": { "type": "int" },
        "country-name": { "type": "string"}
    },
    "required": ["locality", "region", "country-name"]  
}
```

I have an use case, where i need to extract the schema corresponding to each property and send to another service, where it will do validation against the value and save in database. Here is the sample object i need to send to another service.

```
{
  "propertyName": "street-name",
  "value": "19, Canton street",
  **"schema": { "type": "string" }**   
}
```

The questions is,

**how we extract the schema for a particular property from a give JSON schema??**

**Given the property path, Is there any nodejs module exists to do this schema extraction? or if there is any other solutions exists ?**

Because this is very simple scenario, but if we have array, anyOf, OneOf type its getting complicated;

Thanks in advance ! Please let me know if the question is not clear !

sadish

Comment: i did not find any direct solution in specific. But, used JSON editor which is able to get the schema for a property path that we want !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse or query complex JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326405/how-to-parse-or-query-complex-json-in-javascript)