# Is there a way to use ObjectXPathNavigator with JSON.NET?

Tags: .net, json, xpath, json.net

I need to apply XPath to JSON objects. I can use this library to convert JSON to XML and then use XPath. But I was wondering if there's a way to use ObjectXPathNavigator on a JSON object of some kind - and would that be faster?

I am taking this approach because there is no standard for JSON queries (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath)). XPath appears to map across well and is a very well know standard.

thanks - dave

Comment: Did you consider using LINQ to objects ? It should do the job

Comment: @MarwanAouida - Is there a url that shows how to best do this? Thanks.