# Getting specific value from JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am using ajax to get a small set of data back from the server which returns JSON data with the following format:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "value": "One"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "value": "Two"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "Three"
        }
    ]
}
```

On the client side, this is assigned to a variable named `response`. I use `response.data` to get the contents.

The question is, is there an easier way to get the value without doing a loop?
I'm kinda looking for something like this `response[id==2].value` which should give me "Two".

I'm open for any suggestions if this is not possible.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath

Comment: I understand your question but in your case this can be done.. `response.data[2-1].value`

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/uHbZt/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/uHbZt/8/) This?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a functional approach and use the [**Array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var matchingResults = JSON['data'].filter(function(x){ return x.id == 2; });
// procede to use matching elements...
```

Comment: Not at all! You made my answer better for me.

Comment: This solution makes my life brighter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you parse it into a javascript object using something like jQuery's [json parse method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), you could just reference the various items in the array like a normal javascript array.

Do it like this:

```
var dataArray = $.parseJSON(myJson).data;

var theFirstData = dataArray[0]; //get the data with id "1"
```

Alternately, if you don't want to use jQuery, you can use `JSON.parse(jsonToParse)`. [Here're the docs for that method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)