# Get only the 4th element in json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json file present like so:

```
{

    "product": {
        images": [
         "13953115",
         "13953112",
         "13953116",
         "13953026",
         "13953021",
         "11519717" 
        ], //etc
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get **only** the 4th element (in example above "13953026") and then use it to append to a div. The code currently looks like this:

```
 $.getJSON('url-to-product?format=json', function(data){
   var images = [];

   // how to select the fourth element?//
   var image = images[4];

   var fourthImage = $('<img src="'+ image +'" width="265" height="340" alt="" />');
   $('.con_images').html(fourthImage);
 });
```

I thought `var image = images[4];` would work but obviously that isn't. I found some usefull posts in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306675/getting-specific-value-from-json-using-javascript) but I don't know how to incorporate that in my code.

Can anybody help me with this? Thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem doing this:

```
$.getJSON('url-to-product?format=json', function(data){

   var image = data.product.images[3];

   var fourthImage = $('<img src="'+ image +'" width="265" height="340" alt="" />');
   $('.con_images').html(fourthImage);
});
```

Please also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: arrays start with index `0`, your `[4]` is actually the 5th element!

Comment: @balexandre Thanks, it just copied the OPs code and didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

To access the fourth element in your Array,

use `obj.product.images[3]`

**Array index starts from 0**