# How to search within sections of a JSON File?S

Tags: json, search

So, lets say I had a JSON File like this:

```json
{
  "content": [
    {
      "word": "cat",
      "adjectives": [
        {
          "type": "textile",
          "adjective": "fluffy"
        },
        {
          "type": "visual",
          "adjective": "small"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "dog",
      "adjectives": [
        {
          "type": "textile",
          "adjective": "fluffy"
        },
        {
          "type": "visual",
          "adjective": "big"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "chocolate",
      "adjectives": [
        {
          "type": "visual",
          "adjective": "small"
        },
        {
          "type": "gustatory",
          "adjective": "sweet"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, say I wanted to search for two words. For example, "Fluffy" and "Small." The problem with this is that both words' adjectives contain small, and so I would have to manually search for which one contains fluffy. So, how would I do this in a quicker manner?

In other words, how would I find the word(s) with both "fluffy" and "small"

EDIT: Sorry, new asker. Anything that words in a terminal is fair game. `jq` is a really great JSON searcher, and so this is preferred, and sorry for the confusion. I also fixed the JSON

Comment: Could use the Array.filter method? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306675/getting-specific-value-from-json-using-javascript).

Comment: @aOSiOSDev I can see how this would help, but I don t know how I would implement it here... Could I see an example?

Comment: @TheGamingWeirdo where do you want to do this? Which programming language? Do you write a program which handles this JSON or is it a file on your file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A command-line solution would be to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq -r '.content[] | select(.adjectives[].adjective == "fluffy") | .word' /pathToJsonFile.json
```

Output:

```
cat
```

Are you looking for something like this? Do you need a solution that uses other programming languages?

(P.S. your JSON example appears to be invalid)

Comment: After fiddling with this, I figured it out. Basically, to search for multiple, you just use `and` So, like this: `jq -r '.content[] | select(.adjectives[].adjective == "fluffy") and select(.adjectives[].adjective == "small") | .word' /pathToJsonFile.json
`

Answer (score 0):

Since [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is now fair game (this was only clarified later in the comments), here is one solution using jq.

First, fix the JSON to be actually valid:

```json
{
  "content": [
    {
      "word": "cat",
      "adjectives": [
        {
          "type": "textile",
          "adjective": "fluffy"
        },
        {
          "type": "visual",
          "adjective": "small"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "dog",
      "adjectives": [
        {
          "type": "textile",
          "adjective": "fluffy"
        },
        {
          "type": "visual",
          "adjective": "big"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "chocolate",
      "adjectives": [
        {
          "type": "visual",
          "adjective": "small"
        },
        {
          "type": "gustatory",
          "adjective": "sweet"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, the following jq filter returns an array containing the words which contain both adjectives:

```
.content
| map(
    select(
        .adjectives as $adj
        | all("small","fluffy"; IN($adj[].adjective))
    )
    | .word
)
```

If a non-array output is required, and only one word per line, use `.[]` instead of `map` (either after `content` or as a final filter), e.g.:

```
jq -r '.content[]
    | select(
        .adjectives as $adj
        | all("small","fluffy"; IN($adj[].adjective))
    )
    | .word'
```