# Java access Json property with dynamic access formula

Tags: java, json

I want to implement a function that takes an json as argument as well as an access formula which describes the path to a property.

```
public String accessJsonDynamically(JSONObject json, String formula) {
    //
}
```

For example the `a[0].b.prop1` along with the example json should return foo.

```
 {
    "a": [{
        "b": {
            "prop1": "foo",
            "prop2": "bar"
        }
    }, {
        "c": {
            "prop1": "bar"
        }
    }],
    "d": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dynamic formula is otherwise known as a 'JSONPath' - see [this existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath) on the matter.

M.