# Matching JSON Keys

Tags: python, json

When data come from JSON in the format below, I can turn it into a dictionary in **Python**. However, the information is not always in the same order. For instance, `first_name`, I would assume is always 0. However, when I get the data, depending on the form used, may be in the 2 position. So now, instead of storing `first_name` in the right db field, it may be in the `email` field.

Here's my question: how do I ensure the value matches the db field using the `name` key, value?

```
{
  "name": "first_name", 
  "values": [
    "Joe"
  ]
},
{
  "name":"last_name",
  "values": [
    "Example"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "email", 
  "values": [
    "joe@example.com"
  ]
}
```

Thank you, as always! :-)

---

Update
Here's how I access the code:

```
first_name = data['field_data'][0]['values'][0].encode('utf-8')
last_name = data['field_data'][1]['values'][0].encode('utf-8')
email = data['field_data'][2]['values'][0].encode('utf-8')
telephone = data['field_data'][3]['values'][0].encode('utf-8')
```

I'm making the assumption that `first_name` will always be at **0**, even though that's not the case. The Python saves the data, it's putting emails in places where first_name should be. I'm trying to find a way to verify the JSON `name` key corresponds with the same db field before submitting the data.

Comment: By accessing the dictionary appropriately?

Comment: Are you missing square-brackets? What you have is not valid JSON.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's just an example.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I need to make sure that when the form is submitted, the `name` key matches my db model and then submits the appropriate `values`.

Comment: @joshlsullivan Well, I'm not sure what you are talking about. Can you perhaps expand on you example or at least show us the code that isn't working, the results you get, and the results you expect?

Comment: Why are you submitting the name separately from the values in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, example JSON that's not a valid JSON without any code isn't really helpful. Also if you are generating the JSON yourself, you might want to  do something like `{"data":[{"email":{"value":"joe@example.com"}}]}`

Comment: I updated my question. I'm looking for a way to confirm that key `name` corresponds to the key `values` before submitting the data, instead of using its position in the dictionary.

Comment: @joshlsullivan You are *not* using its position in the dictionary. Dictionaries are unordered. This is why your question is confusing. You are probably getting a list of dictionaries. Is the problem that you can't know ahead of time the order in the list? Because that isn't an issue with the way the json is deserialized.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on the order which, as you indicated, is fragile, you should actually look for the element which has the name you want by iterating on the array.

For example:

```
data = {
    'field_data' : [
        {
          "name": "first_name", 
          "values": [
            "Joe"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name":"last_name",
          "values": [
            "Example"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "email", 
          "values": [
            "joe@example.com"
          ]
        }
    ]
}

def get_values(name):
    for data_element in data.get('field_data'):
        if data_element.get('name') == name:
            return data_element.get('values')

    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":

    first_name = get_values('first_name')[0]
    last_name = get_values('last_name')[0] 
    email = get_values('email')[0]

    print 'first_name: ' + first_name
    print 'last_name: ' + last_name
    print 'email: ' + email
```

In this example, the `get_values` function looks for the element which has the desired name. Then, at the very bottom of the example, we use it to retrieve `first_name`, `last_name` and `email`.

Comment: I love that you made it a function. I'm working inside a Django class and not sure how to make it there. I'll keep working on it, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

assuming

```
data = {"field_data":[{
  "name": "first_name", 
  "values": [
    "Joe"
  ]
},
{
  "name":"last_name",
  "values": [
    "Example"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "email", 
  "values": [
    "joe@example.com"
  ]
}]}
```

This is fairly easy way to iterate over all of your fields and if you find a match for what you are looking for, just assign to it. So add more ifs for the rest of your desired data

```
for thing in data['field_data']:
    if thing['name'] == 'first_name':
        first_name = thing['values'][0]
```

Comment: I knew it would be a super simple solution. Thank you!