# XPath equivalent for JSON

Tags: json

Is there a generally accepted XPath equivalent for JSON?

I'm looking for a syntax that has libraries available for most languages/platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) be what you are looking for? There's a [Java](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) and [C#](https://github.com/atifaziz/JSONPath) implementation of it and most likely others too.

Comment: C# Link (https://github.com/atifaziz/JSONPath) wouldn't let me post more than 2 links :(

Comment: I'm a little nervous about using something whose primary documentation appears to be an old blog post, but it certainly meets all of my criteria.

Comment: I know what you mean. When I saw it I was a bit hesitant to post it here but after a bit more google searching it seems to be the most recommended option.

Comment: Please, note that the latest XPath spec has **native** JSON support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509394/10976040