# transversing multidemensional JSONarray

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
{
"response": [
{
  "address": {
    "features": {
        ..........
    },
    "loc": {
      "latitude": 27.32423423423,
      "longitude": -84.0342423429
    },
    "blah1": "blah",
    "blah2": "blah",
    "stuff": {
      "stuff2": "stuff",
      "stuff3": "stuff"
    },
    "data": {
      .....
      },
      "interesting": {
        ...
      }
    },
    "l": null,
    "u": null
  },
  "a": null,
  "b": 0,
  "c": {
    ....
  },
  "d": "test",
  "type": null,
  "id": 53,
  "metadata": {
    ....
  },
  "asset": {
    "pack": [
      {
      ....
      }
    ]
  },
  "k": null,
  "z": null,
  "f": null
}
]}
```

Is there a way to get values from keys: "latitude" and "longitude" from "loc" and store them in global variables (in java) in a quick and efficient matter without having to loop through the JSONArray?

When I try loop through the JSON array, the variables that would hold the values for those keys would not be accessible outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/). But I've no experience with it.

Have a look at this [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath).

Comment: nice answer and good read! I did read into it, but decided that instead of the import, I went about it the old fashion way, make the JSONArray into an object, transverse it, then put it back into a string, then back to an object and then back to an array until I got the key I wanted and stored it into a String. It was a bit messy at first, but it really does give you full control over the structure! Cheers!