# How to find specific element in JSON without model

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath, jjaql

I have a JSON data like this …

```
{
{
   "School": "ABC School",
    "School Address": [
{
  "Office": "Road No 123"
},
{
  "Admin Office": "Road No 321"
},
{
  "Admission Office": "Road No 456"
}
],
 "School Brach": [
{
  "Brach name": "North Brach",
  "Brach Id ": "001",
  "Brach Contact": [
    {
      "Primary Phone": "12345676890",
      "AllowExternal":true
    },
    {
      "Primary Email": "xyz@school.com"
      "AllowExternal":true
    },
    {
      "Primary fax": "0123456789",
      "AllowExternal":false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "Brach name": "South Brach",
  "Brach Id ": "002"
},
{
  "Brach name": "West Brach",
  "Brach Id ": "003"
},
{
  "Brach name": "East Brach",
  "Brach Id ": "004"
}
 ]
}
```

I am getting that JSON from a external call and I have to process that JSON for some element in that JSON.

Like from the above structure suppose I want to get all data for tag “Brach Contact” for “North Brach” where "AllowExternal" is true.

But I do not want to process the complete JSON and do not want to create the model object for the complete JSON structure in my code.

Is there any way I can do that with the JAVA , any external jar or something?

My expected output is JSON structure for "Brach Contact"

```
"Brach Contact": [
    {
      "Primary Phone": "12345676890",
      "AllowExternal":true
    },
    {
      "Primary Email": "xyz@school.com",
      "AllowExternal":true
    }
  ]
```

As input source is external , so there is a chance that they may change the JSON structure , so I what something which is independent of structure rather dependent on tag name. Although that is our next priority.

Please note I am using Spring Boot with JAVA 8

Any one help on this…

Comment: *"I do not want to process the complete JSON"* You have to, at least up to the point where the data you're looking for is. You can short-circuit at that point and not process the rest. --- *"... do not want to create the model object for the complete JSON structure ..."* Then look for a **streaming** JSON parser.

Comment: I think you want to look at this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at **JSONPath**.

I found a nice introduction article here: https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath.

However, if you use this, you WILL need to put in the full path to the target element. But this will also *parse* the whole JSON, without you having to setup *models* and such.

If you don't want to parse the JSON then I suggest that you take a look at **JSON Streaming Parsers**.

Jackson has a stream API: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api