# visualize table data from JSON file from azure Form Recognizer

Tags: json, excel, azure

I'm using the Azure Form Recognizer to automate some data collection. So it reads a table in PDF and generates a JSON file. (file below). So really looking for some ideas on how to transform the JSON file back into a table (i know it sounds a bit circular - but i need to extract 1 column, for example, data for Q2 2019, and build up a time series). 
I looked at using excel - but the bounding box info is just listed, and I can't work out how to "table" it.
Image of the PDF page and the JSON output from the Azure product. And the excel screenshot on how far i got.
Excel screenshot Data get "JSON"
[RAW Table data PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sWn4.png)

{"status": "success", "pages": [{"number": 1, "height": 841, "width": 595, "clusterId": null, "keyValuePairs": [{"key": [{"text": "**Tokens**", "boundingBox": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}], "value": [{"text": "Q2 2019", "boundingBox": [368.8, 772.1, 391.9, 772.1, 391.9, 766.5, 368.8, 766.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q2 2019", "boundingBox": [408.6, 772.1, 431.7, 772.1, 431.7, 766.5, 408.6, 766.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "H1 2019", "boundingBox": [535.9, 772.1, 558.7, 772.1, 558.7, 766.5, 535.9, 766.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(1)", "boundingBox": [127.2, 766.7, 132.0, 766.7, 132.0, 763.0, 127.2, 763.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q2", "boundingBox": [178.6, 768.6, 186.6, 768.6, 186.6, 763.0, 178.6, 763.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q1", "boundingBox": [218.2, 768.6, 226.2, 768.6, 226.2, 763.0, 218.2, 763.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q4", "boundingBox": [257.7, 768.6, 265.7, 768.6, 265.7, 763.0, 257.7, 763.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q3", "boundingBox": [297.3, 768.6, 305.3, 768.6, 305.3, 763.0, 297.3, 763.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q2", "boundingBox": [336.9, 768.6, 344.9, 768.6, 344.9, 763.0, 336.9, 763.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Coal, by product (tonnes)", "boundingBox": [59.8, 765.2, 127.1, 765.2, 127.1, 759.5, 59.8, 759.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "vs.", "boundingBox": [376.6, 765.2, 384.3, 765.2, 384.3, 759.5, 376.6, 759.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "vs.", "boundingBox": [416.2, 765.2, 423.9, 765.2, 423.9, 759.5, 416.2, 759.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "H1 2019", "boundingBox": [450.7, 765.2, 473.4, 765.2, 473.4, 759.5, 450.7, 759.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "H1 2018", "boundingBox": [495.5, 765.2, 518.2, 765.2, 518.2, 759.5, 495.5, 759.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "vs.", "boundingBox": [543.5, 765.2, 551.1, 765.2, 551.1, 759.5, 543.5, 759.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2019", "boundingBox": [175.9, 761.8, 189.4, 761.8, 189.4, 756.2, 175.9, 756.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2019", "boundingBox": [215.6, 761.8, 229.0, 761.8, 229.0, 756.2, 215.6, 756.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2018", "boundingBox": [255.1, 761.8, 268.5, 761.8, 268.5, 756.2, 255.1, 756.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2018", "boundingBox": [294.6, 761.8, 308.1, 761.8, 308.1, 756.2, 294.6, 756.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2018", "boundingBox": [334.3, 761.8, 347.7, 761.8, 347.7, 756.2, 334.3, 756.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q1 2019", "boundingBox": [368.9, 758.3, 392.1, 758.3, 392.1, 752.7, 368.9, 752.7], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q2 2018", "boundingBox": [408.6, 758.3, 431.7, 758.3, 431.7, 752.7, 408.6, 752.7], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "H1 2018", "boundingBox": [535.9, 758.3, 558.7, 758.3, 558.7, 752.7, 535.9, 752.7], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Metallurgical Coal (Australia)", "boundingBox": [59.8, 747.3, 141.9, 747.3, 141.9, 741.6, 59.8, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,843,500", "boundingBox": [173.1, 747.3, 199.8, 747.3, 199.8, 741.6, 173.1, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,156,200", "boundingBox": [212.6, 747.3, 239.3, 747.3, 239.3, 741.6, 212.6, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,647,100", "boundingBox": [252.1, 747.3, 278.8, 747.3, 278.8, 741.6, 252.1, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,382,300", "boundingBox": [291.6, 747.3, 318.4, 747.3, 318.4, 741.6, 291.6, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,261,900", "boundingBox": [331.2, 747.3, 358.0, 747.3, 358.0, 741.6, 331.2, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "41%", "boundingBox": [382.9, 747.3, 395.0, 747.3, 395.0, 741.6, 382.9, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "11%", "boundingBox": [422.5, 747.3, 434.6, 747.3, 434.6, 741.6, 422.5, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "9,999,700", "boundingBox": [452.2, 747.3, 478.9, 747.3, 478.9, 741.6, 452.2, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "10,801,100", "boundingBox": [493.9, 747.3, 524.0, 747.3, 524.0, 741.6, 493.9, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(7)%", "boundingBox": [547.2, 747.3, 560.1, 747.3, 560.1, 741.6, 547.2, 741.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Hard Coking Coal", "boundingBox": [63.8, 733.2, 111.2, 733.2, 111.2, 727.6, 63.8, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,958,600", "boundingBox": [173.1, 733.2, 199.8, 733.2, 199.8, 727.6, 173.1, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3,265,100", "boundingBox": [212.6, 733.2, 239.3, 733.2, 239.3, 727.6, 212.6, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,864,600", "boundingBox": [252.1, 733.2, 278.8, 733.2, 278.8, 727.6, 252.1, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,545,800", "boundingBox": [291.6, 733.2, 318.4, 733.2, 318.4, 727.6, 291.6, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,534,800", "boundingBox": [331.2, 733.2, 358.0, 733.2, 358.0, 727.6, 331.2, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "52%", "boundingBox": [382.9, 733.2, 394.9, 733.2, 394.9, 727.6, 382.9, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "9%", "boundingBox": [425.8, 733.2, 434.5, 733.2, 434.5, 727.6, 425.8, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "8,223,700", "boundingBox": [452.2, 733.2, 478.9, 733.2, 478.9, 727.6, 452.2, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "9,388,100", "boundingBox": [497.3, 733.2, 524.0, 733.2, 524.0, 727.6, 497.3, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(12)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 733.2, 560.1, 733.2, 560.1, 727.6, 543.9, 727.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "PCI / SSCC", "boundingBox": [63.8, 719.1, 95.4, 719.1, 95.4, 713.4, 63.8, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "884,900", "boundingBox": [178.0, 719.1, 199.8, 719.1, 199.8, 713.4, 178.0, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "891,100", "boundingBox": [217.5, 719.1, 239.3, 719.1, 239.3, 713.4, 217.5, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "782,500", "boundingBox": [257.0, 719.1, 278.8, 719.1, 278.8, 713.4, 257.0, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "836,500", "boundingBox": [296.6, 719.1, 318.4, 719.1, 318.4, 713.4, 296.6, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "727,100", "boundingBox": [336.2, 719.1, 358.0, 719.1, 358.0, 713.4, 336.2, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(1)%", "boundingBox": [382.1, 719.1, 394.9, 719.1, 394.9, 713.4, 382.1, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "22%", "boundingBox": [422.5, 719.1, 434.5, 719.1, 434.5, 713.4, 422.5, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "1,776,000", "boundingBox": [452.2, 719.1, 478.9, 719.1, 478.9, 713.4, 452.2, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "1,413,000", "boundingBox": [497.3, 719.1, 524.0, 719.1, 524.0, 713.4, 497.3, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "26%", "boundingBox": [547.9, 719.1, 560.0, 719.1, 560.0, 713.4, 547.9, 713.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Thermal Coal", "boundingBox": [59.8, 704.4, 97.9, 704.4, 97.9, 698.8, 59.8, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "9,460,700", "boundingBox": [173.1, 704.4, 199.8, 704.4, 199.8, 698.8, 173.1, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "9,245,000", "boundingBox": [212.6, 704.4, 239.3, 704.4, 239.3, 698.8, 212.6, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "10,613,700", "boundingBox": [248.7, 704.4, 278.8, 704.4, 278.8, 698.8, 248.7, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "10,816,800", "boundingBox": [288.3, 704.4, 318.4, 704.4, 318.4, 698.8, 288.3, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "10,271,300", "boundingBox": [327.9, 704.4, 357.9, 704.4, 357.9, 698.8, 327.9, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2%", "boundingBox": [386.2, 704.4, 395.0, 704.4, 395.0, 698.8, 386.2, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(8)%", "boundingBox": [421.8, 704.4, 434.6, 704.4, 434.6, 698.8, 421.8, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "18,705,600", "boundingBox": [448.9, 704.4, 478.9, 704.4, 478.9, 698.8, 448.9, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "22,221,600", "boundingBox": [493.9, 704.4, 524.0, 704.4, 524.0, 698.8, 493.9, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(16)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 704.4, 560.0, 704.4, 560.0, 698.8, 543.9, 698.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Export (Australia)", "boundingBox": [63.8, 690.4, 110.2, 690.4, 110.2, 684.8, 63.8, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "245,200", "boundingBox": [178.0, 690.4, 199.8, 690.4, 199.8, 684.8, 178.0, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "338,500", "boundingBox": [217.5, 690.4, 239.3, 690.4, 239.3, 684.8, 217.5, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "427,600", "boundingBox": [257.0, 690.4, 278.8, 690.4, 278.8, 684.8, 257.0, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "455,100", "boundingBox": [296.6, 690.4, 318.4, 690.4, 318.4, 684.8, 296.6, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "289,900", "boundingBox": [336.2, 690.4, 358.0, 690.4, 358.0, 684.8, 336.2, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(28)%", "boundingBox": [378.9, 690.4, 395.0, 690.4, 395.0, 684.8, 378.9, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(15)%", "boundingBox": [418.5, 690.4, 434.6, 690.4, 434.6, 684.8, 418.5, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "583,700", "boundingBox": [457.1, 690.4, 478.9, 690.4, 478.9, 684.8, 457.1, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "498,600", "boundingBox": [502.2, 690.4, 524.0, 690.4, 524.0, 684.8, 502.2, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "17%", "boundingBox": [547.9, 690.4, 560.0, 690.4, 560.0, 684.8, 547.9, 684.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(2)", "boundingBox": [119.7, 677.3, 124.5, 677.3, 124.5, 673.5, 119.7, 673.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Export (South Africa)", "boundingBox": [63.8, 676.2, 119.5, 676.2, 119.5, 670.6, 63.8, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,575,000", "boundingBox": [173.1, 676.2, 199.8, 676.2, 199.8, 670.6, 173.1, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,417,000", "boundingBox": [212.6, 676.2, 239.3, 676.2, 239.3, 670.6, 212.6, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,537,100", "boundingBox": [252.1, 676.2, 278.8, 676.2, 278.8, 670.6, 252.1, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,054,400", "boundingBox": [291.6, 676.2, 318.4, 676.2, 318.4, 670.6, 291.6, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,439,600", "boundingBox": [331.2, 676.2, 358.0, 676.2, 358.0, 670.6, 331.2, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4%", "boundingBox": [386.2, 676.2, 394.9, 676.2, 394.9, 670.6, 386.2, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3%", "boundingBox": [425.8, 676.2, 434.5, 676.2, 434.5, 670.6, 425.8, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "8,991,900", "boundingBox": [452.2, 676.2, 479.0, 676.2, 479.0, 670.6, 452.2, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "8,767,100", "boundingBox": [497.3, 676.2, 524.0, 676.2, 524.0, 670.6, 497.3, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3%", "boundingBox": [551.3, 676.2, 560.0, 676.2, 560.0, 670.6, 551.3, 670.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(3)", "boundingBox": [112.3, 663.2, 117.1, 663.2, 117.1, 659.5, 112.3, 659.5], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Export (Colombia)", "boundingBox": [63.8, 662.2, 112.2, 662.2, 112.2, 656.6, 63.8, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,016,900", "boundingBox": [173.1, 662.2, 199.8, 662.2, 199.8, 656.6, 173.1, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,199,300", "boundingBox": [212.6, 662.2, 239.3, 662.2, 239.3, 656.6, 212.6, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,356,500", "boundingBox": [252.1, 662.2, 278.8, 662.2, 278.8, 656.6, 252.1, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,657,600", "boundingBox": [291.6, 662.2, 318.4, 662.2, 318.4, 656.6, 291.6, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,761,500", "boundingBox": [331.2, 662.2, 358.0, 662.2, 358.0, 656.6, 331.2, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(8)%", "boundingBox": [382.1, 662.2, 394.9, 662.2, 394.9, 656.6, 382.1, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(27)%", "boundingBox": [418.5, 662.2, 434.6, 662.2, 434.6, 656.6, 418.5, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,216,200", "boundingBox": [452.2, 662.2, 478.9, 662.2, 478.9, 656.6, 452.2, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,205,800", "boundingBox": [497.3, 662.2, 524.0, 662.2, 524.0, 656.6, 497.3, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(19)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 662.2, 560.1, 662.2, 560.1, 656.6, 543.9, 656.6], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Domestic (South Africa)", "boundingBox": [63.8, 648.0, 127.2, 648.0, 127.2, 642.4, 63.8, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,623,600", "boundingBox": [173.1, 648.0, 199.8, 648.0, 199.8, 642.4, 173.1, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,290,200", "boundingBox": [212.6, 648.0, 239.3, 648.0, 239.3, 642.4, 212.6, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3,292,500", "boundingBox": [252.1, 648.0, 278.8, 648.0, 278.8, 642.4, 252.1, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,649,700", "boundingBox": [291.6, 648.0, 318.4, 648.0, 318.4, 642.4, 291.6, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,780,300", "boundingBox": [331.2, 648.0, 358.0, 648.0, 358.0, 642.4, 331.2, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "15%", "boundingBox": [382.9, 648.0, 394.9, 648.0, 394.9, 642.4, 382.9, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(6)%", "boundingBox": [421.8, 648.0, 434.5, 648.0, 434.5, 642.4, 421.8, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,913,800", "boundingBox": [452.2, 648.0, 479.0, 648.0, 479.0, 642.4, 452.2, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "7,750,100", "boundingBox": [497.3, 648.0, 524.0, 648.0, 524.0, 642.4, 497.3, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(37)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 648.0, 560.0, 648.0, 560.0, 642.4, 543.9, 642.4], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Total coal production", "boundingBox": [59.8, 633.5, 120.8, 633.5, 120.8, 627.9, 59.8, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "15,304,200", "boundingBox": [169.7, 633.5, 199.8, 633.5, 199.8, 627.9, 169.7, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "13,401,200", "boundingBox": [209.2, 633.5, 239.3, 633.5, 239.3, 627.9, 209.2, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "16,260,800", "boundingBox": [248.7, 633.5, 278.8, 633.5, 278.8, 627.9, 248.7, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "16,199,100", "boundingBox": [288.3, 633.5, 318.4, 633.5, 318.4, 627.9, 288.3, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "15,533,200", "boundingBox": [327.9, 633.5, 357.9, 633.5, 357.9, 627.9, 327.9, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "14%", "boundingBox": [382.9, 633.5, 395.0, 633.5, 395.0, 627.9, 382.9, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(1)%", "boundingBox": [421.8, 633.5, 434.6, 633.5, 434.6, 627.9, 421.8, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "28,705,300", "boundingBox": [448.9, 633.5, 478.9, 633.5, 478.9, 627.9, 448.9, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "33,022,700", "boundingBox": [493.9, 633.5, 524.0, 633.5, 524.0, 627.9, 493.9, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(13)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 633.5, 560.0, 633.5, 560.0, 627.9, 543.9, 627.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Sales volumes", "boundingBox": [59.8, 618.9, 101.5, 618.9, 101.5, 613.2, 59.8, 613.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Metallurgical Coal (Australia)", "boundingBox": [59.8, 604.8, 141.9, 604.8, 141.9, 599.2, 59.8, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,987,300", "boundingBox": [173.1, 604.8, 199.8, 604.8, 199.8, 599.2, 173.1, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3,921,700", "boundingBox": [212.6, 604.8, 239.3, 604.8, 239.3, 599.2, 212.6, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,812,700", "boundingBox": [252.1, 604.8, 278.8, 604.8, 278.8, 599.2, 252.1, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,442,800", "boundingBox": [291.6, 604.8, 318.4, 604.8, 318.4, 599.2, 291.6, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,094,500", "boundingBox": [331.2, 604.8, 358.0, 604.8, 358.0, 599.2, 331.2, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "53%", "boundingBox": [382.9, 604.8, 395.0, 604.8, 395.0, 599.2, 382.9, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "18%", "boundingBox": [422.5, 604.8, 434.6, 604.8, 434.6, 599.2, 422.5, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "9,909,000", "boundingBox": [452.2, 604.8, 479.0, 604.8, 479.0, 599.2, 452.2, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "10,727,400", "boundingBox": [493.9, 604.8, 524.0, 604.8, 524.0, 599.2, 493.9, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(8)%", "boundingBox": [547.2, 604.8, 560.1, 604.8, 560.1, 599.2, 547.2, 599.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Hard Coking Coal", "boundingBox": [63.8, 590.7, 111.2, 590.7, 111.2, 585.0, 63.8, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,944,300", "boundingBox": [173.1, 590.7, 199.8, 590.7, 199.8, 585.0, 173.1, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3,290,600", "boundingBox": [212.6, 590.7, 239.3, 590.7, 239.3, 585.0, 212.6, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,064,200", "boundingBox": [252.1, 590.7, 278.8, 590.7, 278.8, 585.0, 252.1, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,834,100", "boundingBox": [291.6, 590.7, 318.4, 590.7, 318.4, 585.0, 291.6, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,402,800", "boundingBox": [331.2, 590.7, 358.0, 590.7, 358.0, 585.0, 331.2, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "50%", "boundingBox": [382.9, 590.7, 394.9, 590.7, 394.9, 585.0, 382.9, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "12%", "boundingBox": [422.5, 590.7, 434.5, 590.7, 434.5, 585.0, 422.5, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "8,234,900", "boundingBox": [452.2, 590.7, 479.0, 590.7, 479.0, 585.0, 452.2, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "9,288,300", "boundingBox": [497.3, 590.7, 524.0, 590.7, 524.0, 585.0, 497.3, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(11)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 590.7, 560.1, 590.7, 560.1, 585.0, 543.9, 585.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "PCI / SSCC", "boundingBox": [63.8, 576.6, 95.4, 576.6, 95.4, 571.0, 63.8, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "1,043,000", "boundingBox": [173.1, 576.6, 199.8, 576.6, 199.8, 571.0, 173.1, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "631,100", "boundingBox": [217.5, 576.6, 239.3, 576.6, 239.3, 571.0, 217.5, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "748,500", "boundingBox": [257.0, 576.6, 278.8, 576.6, 278.8, 571.0, 257.0, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "608,700", "boundingBox": [296.6, 576.6, 318.4, 576.6, 318.4, 571.0, 296.6, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "691,700", "boundingBox": [336.2, 576.6, 358.0, 576.6, 358.0, 571.0, 336.2, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "65%", "boundingBox": [382.9, 576.6, 394.9, 576.6, 394.9, 571.0, 382.9, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "51%", "boundingBox": [422.5, 576.6, 434.5, 576.6, 434.5, 571.0, 422.5, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "1,674,100", "boundingBox": [452.2, 576.6, 479.0, 576.6, 479.0, 571.0, 452.2, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "1,439,100", "boundingBox": [497.3, 576.6, 524.0, 576.6, 524.0, 571.0, 497.3, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "16%", "boundingBox": [547.9, 576.6, 560.0, 576.6, 560.0, 571.0, 547.9, 571.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Thermal Coal", "boundingBox": [59.8, 562.0, 97.9, 562.0, 97.9, 556.3, 59.8, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "12,046,300", "boundingBox": [169.7, 562.0, 199.8, 562.0, 199.8, 556.3, 169.7, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "12,265,900", "boundingBox": [209.2, 562.0, 239.3, 562.0, 239.3, 556.3, 209.2, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "13,700,800", "boundingBox": [248.7, 562.0, 278.8, 562.0, 278.8, 556.3, 248.7, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "11,782,900", "boundingBox": [288.3, 562.0, 318.4, 562.0, 318.4, 556.3, 288.3, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "12,904,300", "boundingBox": [327.9, 562.0, 358.0, 562.0, 358.0, 556.3, 327.9, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(2)%", "boundingBox": [382.1, 562.0, 395.0, 562.0, 395.0, 556.3, 382.1, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(7)%", "boundingBox": [421.8, 562.0, 434.6, 562.0, 434.6, 556.3, 421.8, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "24,312,400", "boundingBox": [448.9, 562.0, 479.0, 562.0, 479.0, 556.3, 448.9, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "27,132,100", "boundingBox": [493.9, 562.0, 524.0, 562.0, 524.0, 556.3, 493.9, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(10)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 562.0, 560.0, 562.0, 560.0, 556.3, 543.9, 556.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Export (Australia)", "boundingBox": [63.8, 547.8, 110.2, 547.8, 110.2, 542.2, 63.8, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "270,900", "boundingBox": [178.0, 547.8, 199.8, 547.8, 199.8, 542.2, 178.0, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "451,200", "boundingBox": [217.5, 547.8, 239.3, 547.8, 239.3, 542.2, 217.5, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "582,200", "boundingBox": [257.0, 547.8, 278.8, 547.8, 278.8, 542.2, 257.0, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "331,600", "boundingBox": [296.6, 547.8, 318.4, 547.8, 318.4, 542.2, 296.6, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "357,800", "boundingBox": [336.2, 547.8, 358.0, 547.8, 358.0, 542.2, 336.2, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(40)%", "boundingBox": [378.9, 547.8, 395.0, 547.8, 395.0, 542.2, 378.9, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(24)%", "boundingBox": [418.5, 547.8, 434.6, 547.8, 434.6, 542.2, 418.5, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "722,100", "boundingBox": [457.1, 547.8, 479.0, 547.8, 479.0, 542.2, 457.1, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "651,600", "boundingBox": [502.2, 547.8, 524.0, 547.8, 524.0, 542.2, 502.2, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "11%", "boundingBox": [547.9, 547.8, 560.0, 547.8, 560.0, 542.2, 547.9, 542.2], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(2)", "boundingBox": [119.7, 534.8, 124.5, 534.8, 124.5, 531.1, 119.7, 531.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Export (South Africa)", "boundingBox": [63.8, 533.8, 119.5, 533.8, 119.5, 528.1, 63.8, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,932,400", "boundingBox": [173.1, 533.8, 199.8, 533.8, 199.8, 528.1, 173.1, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,262,800", "boundingBox": [212.6, 533.8, 239.3, 533.8, 239.3, 528.1, 212.6, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,918,700", "boundingBox": [252.1, 533.8, 278.8, 533.8, 278.8, 528.1, 252.1, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3,679,600", "boundingBox": [291.6, 533.8, 318.4, 533.8, 318.4, 528.1, 291.6, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,092,700", "boundingBox": [331.2, 533.8, 358.0, 533.8, 358.0, 528.1, 331.2, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "16%", "boundingBox": [382.9, 533.8, 394.9, 533.8, 394.9, 528.1, 382.9, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "21%", "boundingBox": [422.5, 533.8, 434.5, 533.8, 434.5, 528.1, 422.5, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "9,195,200", "boundingBox": [452.2, 533.8, 478.9, 533.8, 478.9, 528.1, 452.2, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "8,708,400", "boundingBox": [497.3, 533.8, 524.0, 533.8, 524.0, 528.1, 497.3, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "6%", "boundingBox": [551.3, 533.8, 560.0, 533.8, 560.0, 528.1, 551.3, 528.1], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(3)", "boundingBox": [112.3, 520.6, 117.1, 520.6, 117.1, 516.9, 112.3, 516.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Export (Colombia)", "boundingBox": [63.8, 519.6, 112.3, 519.6, 112.3, 514.0, 63.8, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,244,800", "boundingBox": [173.1, 519.6, 199.8, 519.6, 199.8, 514.0, 173.1, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,199,600", "boundingBox": [212.6, 519.6, 239.3, 519.6, 239.3, 514.0, 212.6, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,297,200", "boundingBox": [252.1, 519.6, 278.8, 519.6, 278.8, 514.0, 252.1, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,589,100", "boundingBox": [291.6, 519.6, 318.4, 519.6, 318.4, 514.0, 291.6, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,762,900", "boundingBox": [331.2, 519.6, 358.0, 519.6, 358.0, 514.0, 331.2, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2%", "boundingBox": [386.2, 519.6, 394.9, 519.6, 394.9, 514.0, 386.2, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(19)%", "boundingBox": [418.5, 519.6, 434.6, 519.6, 434.6, 514.0, 418.5, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,444,500", "boundingBox": [452.2, 519.6, 478.9, 519.6, 478.9, 514.0, 452.2, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,243,100", "boundingBox": [497.3, 519.6, 524.0, 519.6, 524.0, 514.0, 497.3, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(15)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 519.6, 560.1, 519.6, 560.1, 514.0, 543.9, 514.0], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Domestic (South Africa)", "boundingBox": [63.8, 505.6, 127.2, 505.6, 127.2, 499.9, 63.8, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,016,700", "boundingBox": [173.1, 505.6, 199.8, 505.6, 199.8, 499.9, 173.1, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,402,800", "boundingBox": [212.6, 505.6, 239.3, 505.6, 239.3, 499.9, 212.6, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "1,947,500", "boundingBox": [252.1, 505.6, 278.8, 505.6, 278.8, 499.9, 252.1, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3,305,800", "boundingBox": [291.6, 505.6, 318.4, 505.6, 318.4, 499.9, 291.6, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "3,146,500", "boundingBox": [331.2, 505.6, 358.0, 505.6, 358.0, 499.9, 331.2, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(16)%", "boundingBox": [378.9, 505.6, 395.0, 505.6, 395.0, 499.9, 378.9, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(36)%", "boundingBox": [418.5, 505.6, 434.6, 505.6, 434.6, 499.9, 418.5, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,419,500", "boundingBox": [452.2, 505.6, 478.9, 505.6, 478.9, 499.9, 452.2, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "7,857,500", "boundingBox": [497.3, 505.6, 524.0, 505.6, 524.0, 499.9, 497.3, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(44)%", "boundingBox": [543.9, 505.6, 560.0, 505.6, 560.0, 499.9, 543.9, 499.9], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Third party sales", "boundingBox": [63.8, 491.4, 108.3, 491.4, 108.3, 485.8, 63.8, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,581,500", "boundingBox": [173.1, 491.4, 199.8, 491.4, 199.8, 485.8, 173.1, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,949,500", "boundingBox": [212.6, 491.4, 239.3, 491.4, 239.3, 485.8, 212.6, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,955,200", "boundingBox": [252.1, 491.4, 278.8, 491.4, 278.8, 485.8, 252.1, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "1,876,800", "boundingBox": [291.6, 491.4, 318.4, 491.4, 318.4, 485.8, 291.6, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "2,544,400", "boundingBox": [331.2, 491.4, 358.0, 491.4, 358.0, 485.8, 331.2, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(12)%", "boundingBox": [378.9, 491.4, 395.0, 491.4, 395.0, 485.8, 378.9, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "1%", "boundingBox": [425.8, 491.4, 434.5, 491.4, 434.5, 485.8, 425.8, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "5,531,100", "boundingBox": [452.2, 491.4, 478.9, 491.4, 478.9, 485.8, 452.2, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "4,671,500", "boundingBox": [497.3, 491.4, 524.0, 491.4, 524.0, 485.8, 497.3, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "18%", "boundingBox": [547.9, 491.4, 560.0, 491.4, 560.0, 485.8, 547.9, 485.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q2 2019", "boundingBox": [374.8, 445.4, 397.9, 445.4, 397.9, 439.8, 374.8, 439.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q2 2019", "boundingBox": [410.5, 445.4, 433.6, 445.4, 433.6, 439.8, 410.5, 439.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "H1 2019", "boundingBox": [532.3, 445.4, 555.1, 445.4, 555.1, 439.8, 532.3, 439.8], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "(1)", "boundingBox": [133.3, 440.0, 138.1, 440.0, 138.1, 436.3, 133.3, 436.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q2", "boundingBox": [178.9, 442.0, 187.0, 442.0, 187.0, 436.3, 178.9, 436.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q1", "boundingBox": [218.8, 442.0, 226.8, 442.0, 226.8, 436.3, 218.8, 436.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q4", "boundingBox": [258.4, 442.0, 266.4, 442.0, 266.4, 436.3, 258.4, 436.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q3", "boundingBox": [298.0, 442.0, 306.0, 442.0, 306.0, 436.3, 298.0, 436.3], "confidence": 1.0}, {"text": "Q2", "boundingBox": [341.2, 442.0, 349.2, 442.0, 349.2, 436.3, 341.2, 436.3], "confidence": 1.0}]}], "tables": []}], "errors": []}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that. Basically what you need is a JSONPath (https://jsonpath.com/) where you'll specify the parts of the json you're interested:

More options available: [Is there a JSON equivalent of XQuery/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath)