# how to extract nested json using sqlite json-extract

Tags: json, sqlite, nested, json-extract, sqlite-json1

How could I extract nested json using sqlite json-extract or other sqlite json command ?

Here I'd like to extract **given_id**

```
"invoices": [{

........


    "items": [{


    "given_id": "TBC0003B",


    ...


        }


    ]

   }

]
```

Thanks.

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite you can use [`json_extract()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex) as follows:

```
select json_extract(my_json_col, '$.invoices[0].items[0].given_id') my_given_id from mytable
```

This gives you the `given_id` attribute of the first element of the `items` array under first element of the `invoices` array.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8e25d774f86bcd0189400b443057426d)**:

```
with mytable as (select '{
    "invoices": [{
        "items": [{ "given_id": "TBC0003B" }] 
    }]
}' my_json_col)
select json_extract(my_json_col, '$.invoices[0].items[0].given_id') my_given_id from mytable
```

```
| my_given_id |
| :---------- |
| TBC0003B    |
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's nested json array and I couldn't know the length of the array. I need to get all **given_id** value for dynamic size of this nested json. How could I achieve it ?

Comment: @kkk: then we would probably need a json table-valued function. The exact query would depend on the structure of the array, and on the result that you expect. You would need to provide this information: a valid and complete json document (no `...`s), and the expected result as tabular text.

Comment: could you please show with example how to do it ? thanks