# Extract specific data from JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

JSON:

```js
{
  "trackResponse": {
    "shipment": [{
      "warnings": [{
        "code": "TW",
        "message": "Tracking Information Not Found"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

In that string I want to retrieve "message" information. Please let know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a JSON equivalent of XQuery/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath)

Answer (score 1):

use flatMap and Map

```js
var data = {
  "trackResponse": {
    "shipment": [{
      "warnings": [{
        "code": "TW",
        "message": "Tracking Information Not Found"
      }]
    }]
  }
};
console.log(data.trackResponse.shipment.flatMap(i=>i.warnings.map(m=>m.message)))
```

Comment: FYI, You are extracting it from an object, the question was about JSON...so You are missing a line ;)

Comment: Can we do this without flatmap and map