# How to get data with nested JSON without create a lots of map method

Tags: javascript, json

**Question 1**

I'll get straight to the point, I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "activities": [
        {
            "activityId": "60f672b20f38640008a6c29b",
            "_id": "610cb887b149cb00095e1eb6",
        
            "trackingProgress": [
                {
                    "_id": "610cb8ee541fea0009189c36",
                    "dateRecorded": "2021-07-16T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "emotion":"Good",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "_id": "610cb8ee541fea0009189c37",
                            "feelingType": "Satisfied",
                            "times": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "611358300fea490008d56ea7",
                    "dateRecorded": "2021-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "emotion":"Bad",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "_id": "6113583b0fea490008d56eae",
                            "feelingType": "Neutral",
                            "times": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "611b6068fed9100009a4f689",
                    "dateRecorded": "2021-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "emotion":"Neutral",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "_id": "611b6068fed9100009a4f68a",
                            "feelingType": "Satisfied",
                            "times": 4
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "title": "Losing & Managing Weight",
            "description": "Losing weight",
            "order": null,
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "tuesday"
            ],
            "reminderTimeAt": "09:00 am",
            "type": "Custom",
            "progressOverview": {
                "notSatisfied": 0,
                "neutral": 1,
                "satisfied": 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to get, for example `id` of `items`, the only method i know is

```
const listActivity = data.activities
  .map((item1) => item1.trackingProgress
  .map((item2) => item2.items
  .map((item3)=>(item3._id))))
```

And it return something like this

```
[
    [
        [
            "610cb8ee541fea0009189c37"
        ],
        [
            "6113583b0fea490008d56eae"
        ],
        [
            "611b6068fed9100009a4f68a"
        ]
    ]
]
```

or
[image]

But i want an array without wrap any of this, if this happen, i will have to use a lots of `map` everytime i want to get data, all i want is just `[id1,id2,id3]` , how can i do that, thank you a lots

**Question 2**

How to make an json with `{}` and with `[]`. I notice use `{}`, we cab access child data by using `.` , but with `[]`, we have to use map, so what is the better way to get data, especially like above array?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use JSONPath.
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i wonder, is there no way we can do this with pure javascript and react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use JSONPath, see the accepted answer here:
[Is there a JSON equivalent of XQuery/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath)

and go over https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/  for some syntax examples.

JSONPath is to JSON what X-Path is to XML.

For your case something like:

jsonPath(yourJsonObj, $.activities.trackingProgress.items._id)

If you are using ES6,
then install it from NPM and import it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but as i know until now there are no way we can't do this with `map`, is that right?

Comment: Oh I understand what you are asking now, hmm let me see, I think it your after  map reduce.

Comment: You may also opt to keep the maps and flatten the result with flat()

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is Map Reduce

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

and for example :

```
 output = foo.reduce((activitiesReducedResultArray, currentActivity) => {
  const trackingProgressResultArray = currentActivity.reduce((trackingProgressReducedResultArray, currentTrackingProgress) => {
    const itemResultsArray = currentTrackingProgress.reduce((itemsReducedResultArray, currentItem) => {
                return itemsReducedResultArray.push(currentItem['_id']) ;                   
        });
            itemsReducedResultArray.concat(idResultsArray);
    });
    return trackingProgressReducedResultArray.concat(itemResultsArray);
  });
  return activitiesReducedResultArray.concat(trackingProgressResultArray)
});
```

consider accumulator as your output array data structure.
and instead of  accumulator + currentValue;  you o

Comment: Updated my answer to your use case.

Comment: Thank you, but i think i will use JSONPath