# JSONPath/JSONQuery filter on key

Tags: javascript, dojo, jsonpath

I know how to use JSONPath in JavaScript [to filter on the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003252/jsonpath-contains-filter):

```
var o = {
  current_user_url: "https://api.github.com/user",
  other_user_url: "https://api.github.com/user",
  otherstuff: "stuff"
};
jsonPath(o, "$.[?(/https.*/.test(@))]") //returns ["https://api.github.com/user"]
```

But how to filter on the keys? I want to have all values returned where the key ends in `*_url`. The following doesn't work since `@` apparently only contains the value of the JSON objects.

```
jsonPath(o, "$.[?(/.*_url/.test(@))]")
```

If it's not possible with JSONPath or JSONQuery, is there another library that's easy to use and setup? I want the user to enter the query-expression, that's why I'd prefer to use a query language instead of just evaling plain JavaScript (like [these guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628949)).

Comment: your intention is to verify attribute name for a specific pattern? or get list of attribute names?

Comment: I want to have all values returned where the key ends in `*_url`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) which extends the global object JSON with the method "search". With this method, you can search a JSON structure with XPath syntax and it returns the matches as an array-like object.

```
var data = {
  current_user_url: "https://api.github.com/user",
  other_user_url: "https://api.github.com/user",
  otherstuff: "stuff"
},
found = JSON.search(data, "//*[substring(name(), string-length(name())-3) = '_url']"),
str = '';

for (var i=0; i<found.length; i++) {
    str += found[i] +'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
```

To see this in action, check out this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/92vCL/