# Find the value of specific element satisfying condition from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays

Friends I have following like json array

```
[
   {
      "Rate":100.0,
      "MaterialID":"BOLT",
      "BrandName":"",
      "Description":"",
      "Unit":"KG",
      "TokenNumber":2
   },
   {
      "Rate":null,
      "MaterialID":"PLYWOOD",
      "BrandName":"",
      "Description":"",
      "Unit":"FT",
      "TokenNumber":2
   },
   {
      "Rate":null,
      "MaterialID":"SCREW 1.5 INCH",
      "BrandName":"",
      "Description":"",
      "Unit":"KG",
      "TokenNumber":2
   }
]
```

I want to know the shortest way to find an element that has `materialID` with value `PLYWOOD`.
I can do it using `for` loop. But I want to know some shortcut for this something like

`var unit = jsonArray[<whiere materialID == 'PLYWOOD']['Unit'];`

**You can use `jQuery` if required.**

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json

Comment: This is not JSON... it seems you are working with an array of objects.

Comment: @FelixKling Now this is a valid json

Comment: Yes, but is your question about JSON? It seems to be about finding elements in an array.

Comment: Please do `alert(typeof jsonArray)`. Does it say `string` or `object`?

Comment: Then it is no longer JSON but a normal javascript object (in this case an array). And yes, it is a huge difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use $.grep

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not required, so you could do it like this:

```
function findItem(arr, key, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ARR.length; i++) {
       if (arr[i][key] === value) {
           return(i);
       }
    }
    return(-1);
}

var plywoodIndex = findItem(data, "MaterialID", "PLYWOOD");
if (plywoodIndex !== -1) {
    // do something with the plywoodIndex object here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Raghaw has suggested. I find the way to do my work. I designed following function that can return the object with specified materialID.

**Assumptions: `materials` is the array**

```
function getMaterialFromArray(materialID) {
    return $.grep(materials, function (n, i) {
        return(n.MaterialID == materialID);
    })[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shashwat. your answer helps me after 4 years

Comment: @ubiquitous I am glad to hear that it helped you.