# Javascript objects matching

Tags: javascript

A Javascript object can be used as an associative array.
So my question is how can I automatically set that multiple key's with the same ending match one value?

I'll write an example to be more explicit on what I want.
Something like this:

```
var handle = {}
handle[*css] = handlers.style;
```

Every key that ends with "css" should be matched to handlers.style.

Any way to doing this?

PD: Im doing this with server-side javascript with NodeJS

Comment: You might be interested in the question [Is there a query language for JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json)

Comment: You can't. Not without either defining your own method or simply iterating over all properties of the object.

Comment: Using node? Look at node-proxy (https://github.com/samshull/node-proxy). You can create a catch-all handler for getters/setters. It can be done.

Comment: @999 - Yet another reason for me to finally sit down and get to grips properly with node! I knew of the Harmony proposal but had no idea such a thing existed already.

Comment: hacking the route to check this stuff looked as a cleaner way to achieve it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible if you iterate through the object properties and check that the property name matches the desired pattern. Something like:

```
for (var i in obj) {
  if (i.toString().substr(-3) === 'css') {
    obj[i] = handlers.style;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you think its a waste to check if `obj.hasOwnProperty(i)` first?

Comment: When would `i` not be a string? Is `toString()` necessary?

Comment: @lbstr `hasOwnProperty` won't detect inherited properties. Which may or may not be desired: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Description

Comment: @999 The `toString()` isn't needed if you know that `obj` is just an `Object` - and not an `Array` (which may returned numeric keys). It's a bit of defensive programming.

Comment: Even though this answers the question, it can't really be used to a route request to a resource to the correct handler. For instance if 'i' is  mySuperStyle.css, this will not be routed to the handlers.style

Comment: @leepowers, `i` will always be a string, even if you're iterating over an array with `for (var i in y)...`.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way:

```
var handle = {}
name = "article_users_css"
handle[name.substr(name.length-3)] = "something"
```

or if you can use some symbol to delimit the suffix, you can use this instead:

```
name.substr(str.lastIndexOf(YOUR_CHAR_OF_CHOICE))
```

Comment: I'm confused. Wouldn't your example just set `handle["css"]` to `"something"`?

Comment: Yes it does, apparently I misinterpreted the question. But it does achieve the same result (and possibly with a smaller footprint and easier retrieval), so it could be desirable if a list of the property names been set does not need to be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this. But you can the request pathname before routing the request to your handlers. 
See example below:

```
 var path = "mystyle.css"
 // var path = "index.html"
 // var path = "image.png"

 var handle = {};
 handle[css] = handlers.style;
 handle[html] = handlers.html;
 handle[img] = handlers.img;

 if (path.match(/.*\.css/)) {
     handle[css]();
 } 
 else if (path.match(/.*\.html/)) {
       handle[html]();
 }
 else if ((path.match(/.*\.png/) || path.match(/.*\.jpg/)) {
       handle[img]();
 }
```

You can consider using Express that does support routing based on regEx matching