# Get value from deep inside a JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I have this Bing Maps JSON file and I want to retrieve "++formattedAddress++" from inside it

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusDescription": "OK",
    "copyright": "Copyright Â© 2013 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
    "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
    "resourceSets": [
        {
            "resources": [
                {
                    "__type": "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
                    "point": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [
                            63.8185213804245,
                            12.105498909950256
                        ]
                    },
                    "matchCodes": [
                        "Good"
                    ],
                    "address": {
                        "addressLine": "55 Stuff",
                        "locality": "Stuff",
                        "++formattedAddress++": "55 Stuff, 51512 Stuff",
                        "postalCode": "25521",
                        "adminDistrict2": "Stuff-Stuff",
                        "countryRegion": "UK",
                        "adminDistrict": "NL"
                    },
                    "bbox": [
                        84.81465866285382,
                        12.097347537264563,
                        50.822384097995176,
                        7.11365028263595
                    ],
                    "name": "55 Stuff, 51122 Stuff",
                    "confidence": "Medium",
                    "entityType": "Address",
                    "geocodePoints": [
                        {
                            "calculationMethod": "Interpolation",
                            "type": "Point",
                            "usageTypes": [
                                "Display",
                                "Route"
                            ],
                            "coordinates": [
                                50.8185213804245,
                                7.105498909950256
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "estimatedTotal": 1
        }
    ],
    "traceId": "8a13f73cab93472db1253e4c1621c651|BL2M002306|02.00.83.1900|BL2MSNVM001274, BL2MSNVM003152",
    "brandLogoUri": "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png"
}
```

What I have tried so far is like this:

```
final JSONArray jsonMainArr = locationData.getJSONArray("resourceSets").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("resources");
final JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(0);
return childJSONObject.getString("formattedAddress");
```

childJSONObject is still 2-3 levels over formattedAddress and the query is becoming highly inefficient

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. That was fast, how did you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get formattedAddress address value as from current json String :

```
final JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(0)
                                                .getJSONObject("address");
return childJSONObject.getString("++formattedAddress++");
```

Comment: Isn't this too long? Can't you just query the JSON?

Comment: Try reading through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json) question

Comment: Could it be queried if I used XML instead? Or just using XPATH?

Comment: @EfEs : ok see my short answer

Comment: @EfEs : you are missing `getJSONObject("address")` because for `formattedAddress` address in inside address jsonObejct

Comment: @EfEs : if you are using API LEVEL 11 or UP then use [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) for reading json because lots of new methods available to read JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

There are so much online sites where you paste your complex code and get it in an easy way. e.g. http://json.parser.online.fr/