# Extracting values from deeply nested JSON structures

Tags: python, json

This is a structure I'm getting from elsewhere, that is, a list of deeply nested dictionaries:

```
{
    "foo_code": 404,
    "foo_rbody": {
        "query": {
            "info": {
                "acme_no": "444444",
                "road_runner": "123"
            },
            "error": "no_lunch",
            "message": "runner problem."
        }
    },
    "acme_no": "444444",
    "road_runner": "123",
    "xyzzy_code": 200,
    "xyzzy_rbody": {
        "api": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "desc": "OK",
                    "id": 198,
                    "acme_no": "789",
                    "road_runner": "123",
                    "params": {
                        "bicycle": "2wheel",
                        "willie": "hungry",
                        "height": "1",
                        "coyote_id": "1511111"
                    },
                    "activity": "TRAP",
                    "state": "active",
                    "status": 200,
                    "type": "chase"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

{
    "foo_code": 200,
    "foo_rbody": {
        "query": {
            "result": {
                "acme_no": "260060730303258",
                "road_runner": "123",
                "abyss": "26843545600"
            }
        }
    },
    "acme_no": "260060730303258",
    "road_runner": "123",
    "xyzzy_code": 200,
    "xyzzy_rbody": {
        "api": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "desc": "OK",
                    "id": 198,
                    "acme_no": "789",
                    "road_runner": "123",
                    "params": {
                        "bicycle": "2wheel",
                        "willie": "hungry",
                        "height": "1",
                        "coyote_id": "1511111"
                    },
                    "activity": "TRAP",
                    "state": "active",
                    "status": 200,
                    "type": "chase"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Asking for different structures is out of question (legacy apis etc).

So I'm wondering if there's some clever way of extracting selected values from such a structure.

The candidates I was thinking of:

- flatten particular dictionaries, building composite keys, smth like:

  {
   "foo_rbody.query.info.acme_no": "444444",
   "foo_rbody.query.info.road_runner": "123",
   ...
  }

Pro: getting every value with one access and if predictable key is not there, it means that the structure was not there (as you might have noticed, dictionaries may have different structures depending on whether it was successful operation, error happened, etc).

Con: what to do with lists?

- Use some recursive function that would do successive key lookups, say by "foo_rbody", then by "query", "info", etc.

Any better candidates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this rather trivial function to access nested properties:

```
import re

def get_path(dct, path):
    for i, p in re.findall(r'(\d+)|(\w+)', path):
        dct = dct[p or int(i)]
    return dct
```

Usage:

```
value = get_path(data, "xyzzy_rbody.api.items[0].params.bicycle")
```

Comment: Simple, nonrecursive, tight. Why didn't I think about smth like that? Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the function `byPath` in my answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069262/count-non-empty-end-leafs-of-a-python-dicitonary-array-data-structure-recursiv/18069577#18069577) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own path mechanism and then query the complicated dict with paths. Example:

- `/` : get the root object
- `/key`: get the value of `root_object['key']`, e.g. `/foo_code` --> `404`
- `/key/key`: nesting: `/foo_rbody/query/info/acme_no` -> `444444`
- `/key[i]`: get `ith` element of that list, e.g. `/xyzzy_rbody/api/items[0]/desc` --> `"OK"`

The path can also return a dict which you then run more queries on, etc.

It would be fairly easy to implement recursively.

Answer (score 1):

I think about two more solutions:

You can try package [Pynq](https://github.com/heynemann/pynq/wiki), described here - [structured query language for JSON (in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306448/structured-query-language-for-json-in-python). As far as a I understand, it's some kind of LINQ for python.

You may also try to convert your JSON to XML and then use Xquery language to get data from it - [XQuery library under Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133648/xquery-library-under-python)

Comment: pynq is cool, thanks! I'm not sure I will use it (it seems an overkill here) but it's very nice to have such tool.