# retrieving an object in a tree-like angularjs model

Tags: javascript, object, angularjs

Here is a sample model:

```
$scope.people=
   [
{"id":1, "name":"bob", "pets":[
    {"id":1, "name":"Jaco", "type":"parrot"},
    {"id":2, "name":"coco", "type":"parrot"},
    {"id":3, "name":"pluto", "type":"dog"}
    ]},
{"id":2, "name": "jason", "pets":[
    {"id":4, "name":"coco", "type":"cat"}
]},
{"id":3, "name": "kurt", "pets":[
     {"id":5, "name":"nemo", "type":"turtle"},
     {"id":6, "name":"grnx", "type":"lynx"}
]}
];
```

Are there angularjs/javascript functions or best practices to retrieve bob's id, or find the owner of an animal, or extract one pet record with a key/value pattern?

I imagine I can write my own functions to look through the model (recursive or with for loops), but I'd rather use higher level methods if they exist.

Comment: From a logical point of view: How could that function that serves your purpose possibly look like?

Comment: Good question, I was thinking of something like: findObject(ObjectToSearchIn, searchPattern), just something thas would save me writilg al lot of for loops. But the answer below looks like what I was dreaming of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find that there are various options for [querying JS data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json). I find [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) to be excellent. Each of your examples can be done with [one line of linq.js code](http://jsfiddle.net/rnzZ5/).

```
//Get Id
return Enumerable.From($scope.people).First('$.name == "' + name + '"' ).id;            
//Pet owners
return Enumerable.From($scope.people).Where('$.pets.length > 0').Select("$.name").ToArray();            
//Pet Search
return Enumerable.From($scope.people).SelectMany('$.pets').Where('$.' + key + ' == "' + value + '"').Select('$.name').ToArray()
```