# How to query a JSON object

Tags: angularjs, json, json-deserialization

In my AngularJS web app, How can I query a JSON object ?

For example in the below JSON object how can I find the value of **reportTypeLabel**  where **reportTypeId=3**

**JSON:**

```
[  
   {  
      reportTypeId:5,
      reportTypeCode:"FINREP",
      reportTypeLabel:"Financial Reporting"
   },
   {  
      reportTypeId:9000002,
      reportTypeCode:"REM HE",
      reportTypeLabel:"High Earners"
   },
   {  
      reportTypeId:3,
      reportTypeCode:"COREP LE",
      reportTypeLabel:"Large Exposures - COREP"
   }
]
```

Comment: Related question: [Is there a query language for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/777455/195835)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use data manipulation extensively, I'd highly recommend using a JS library, like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

For example, using **underscore**:

```
// assuming your object is called data

var result = _.findWhere(data, {
    reportTypeId: 3
}).reportTypeLabel;
// result === 'Large Exposures - COREP'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can require $filter service and do

`var elements = $filter('filter')(arrayOfObjects,{reportTypeId: 3});`

elements will be an array of all the elements with that 'reportTypeId'
i would recommend reading about angular filters and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
<div ng-repeat="report in reports | filter:{reportTypeId:'3'}">
    {{report.reportTypeCode}}
</div>
```

Working [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/f2d4t20w/1/)

Comment: Many thanks. Would there be any performance issue if the volume of data is very huge ?     when compared with the below underscore approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function on array:

```
var items = [
  {reportTypeId:5, reportTypeCode:"FINREP"},
  {reportTypeId:9000002, reportTypeCode:"REM HE"}
];
var onlyMatching = items.filter(function(item){ return item.reportTypeId == 3; });
```

Or an angular [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {reportTypeId: '3'}">{{item. reportTypeLabel}}</div>
```

Or an angular [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) through [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) service

```
module.controller('ItemsCtrl', function($filter){
  $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.items,{ reportTypeId: '3' });
});
```