# Query a JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, json-deserialization

I am trying to query a JSON object using underscore library but I am unable to query the below JSON structure. '$scope.conScopeFreqStartDates' variable has the below JSON value.

I am passing 'frequencyCodeInput' value has 'Y' in the underscore script.

```
    [
       {
          "consolidationScopeId": 4008,
          "consolidationScopeCode": "S",
          "consolidationScopeLabel": "Individual",
          "frequencies": [
             {
                "frequencyCode": "M",
                "frequencyLabel": "Monthly",
                "startDates": [
                   "2016-01-31",
                   "2016-02-28"
                ]
             },
             {
                "frequencyCode": "Y",
                "frequencyLabel": "Annual",
                "startDates": [
                   "2016-12-31",
                   "2017-12-31"
                ]
             }
          ]
       }]
```

I am trying to get the startDates from the JSON object,

controller

```
var startDates = _.findWhere($scope.conScopeFreqStartDates, {
            'frequencies.frequencyCode': frequencyCodeInput
        }).startDates;

        $scope.startDates = startDates;
```

'startDates' is undefined for my above code.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking here. You can query a JSON object like this: `object["key"]` Why do you need Underscore?

Comment: he wants to get the value of startDates for the frequency that has a frequencyCode equal to frequencyCodeInput. [].filter() would do the job, underscore may have a method that might make it easier.

Comment: I am implementing something similar to this 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883332/how-to-query-a-json-object'  . But unable to query my JSOn structure which i posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I would call _.findWhere on the frequencies array on your object, not the entire object

```
var startDates = _.findWhere($scope.conScopeFreqStartDates.frequencies, {
            'frequencyCode': frequencyCodeInput
        }).startDates;

        $scope.startDates = startDates;
```

Comment: This really helped me a lot. Thanks Scott.