# How to query a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, xpath, typescript, jsonpath

### Here is the file I would like to parse

1. I receive a file from a webservice in JSON format.
2. I would like to parse the content in such a way that I display the name of the president from the USA

> ```
> {
>     "response": {
>         "result": {
>             "Countries": {
>                 "row": [
>                     {
>                         "no": "1",
>                         "FL": [
>                             {
>                                 "content": "USA",
>                                 "val": "Country"
>                             },
>                             {
>                                 "content": "Barack Obama",
>                                 "val": "President"
>                             }
>                         ]
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "no": "2",
>                         "FL": [
>                             {
>                                 "content": "Cuba",
>                                 "val": "Country"
>                             },
>                             {
>                                 "content": "Raul Castro",
>                                 "val": "President"
>                             }
>                         ]
>                     }
>                 ]
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

### The expected output

```
{ presidents: [
    { "name": "Barack Obama"}
    ]
}
```

### could you provide a solution using a kind of JSON XPath?

Comment: Are you okay with a command-line solution?

Comment: You can use jq command line tool for querying a json file.

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Similar question: [Is there a query language for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/777455/195835)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = {
    "response": {
        "result": {
            "Countries": {
                "row": [
                    {
                        "no": "1",
                        "FL": [
                            {
                                "content": "USA",
                                "val": "Country"
                            },
                            {
                                "content": "Barack Obama",
                                "val": "President"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "no": "2",
                        "FL": [
                            {
                                "content": "Cuba",
                                "val": "Country"
                            },
                            {
                                "content": "Raul Castro",
                                "val": "President"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
res={};//Here we will store result
for (i in t.response.result.Countries.row) {
  // get current country
  country = t.response.result.Countries.row[i].FL[0].content;
  // get current president
  president = t.response.result.Countries.row[i].FL[1].content;
  if (country == 'USA') {
    res.presidents=[{name:president}];
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @almasK89, thank you for the answer, do you know an answer using a kind of JSON XPath? You solution is certainly correct and I would like to find a more generic solution in case the data model of the json changes in the future. Thanks

Comment: http://techslides.com/how-to-parse-and-search-json-in-javascript found this solution

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you are loading the response into a variable data:

```
var data = {
    "response" : {
        "result" : {
            "Countries" : {
                "row" : [{
                        "no" : "1",
                        "FL" : [{
                                "content" : "USA",
                                "val" : "Country"
                            }, {
                                "content" : "Barack Obama",
                                "val" : "President"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "no" : "2",
                        "FL" : [{
                                "content" : "Cuba",
                                "val" : "Country"
                            }, {
                                "content" : "Raul Castro",
                                "val" : "President"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

You can then filter your data like this:

```
data.response.result.Countries.row.filter(function (el) {
    return (el.FL[0].content == "USA");
})[0].FL[1];
```

To get to:

```
{
    "content" : "Barack Obama",
    "val" : "President"
}
```

To get the name, simply specify "content"

```
data.response.result.Countries.row.filter(function(el){
  return (el.FL[0].content == "USA");
})[0].FL[1].content;
```

**EDIT 1**

One could search a json object like a string.

If we know that the element will have no children, then we could use something like this:

```
function find(query,obj) {
  var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
  var start = str.substr(0,str.indexOf(query)).lastIndexOf('{');
  var end = str.substr(start,str.length).indexOf('}');
  return str.substr(start,end);
}

console.log(find('"content":"USA"',data))
```

Comment: hi @emil-s-jørgensen, thank you for the answer, do you know an answer using a kind of JSON XPath? You solution is certainly correct and I would like to find a more generic solution in case the data model of the json changes in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Despite of the age of the question I want to add this answer as reference for future visitors with the same problem:

You can use [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/). The page contains a description and an implementation in JavaScript and PHP.