# Without looping get the index position in a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have the following `JSONObject`

```
{"results":2,"object":[{"id":10,"rank":12},{"id":21,"rank":22}.........{"id":n,"rank":n}]}
```

Now if I have an id: 21, how do I get the position of that object?

Is there any direct way to get the position of that id?

Like 21 is in 2nd position in that array.So the index position is 1. Is there any direct way without looping the `JSONArray` to improve the performance?

Comment: Sorry thats by mistake. Corrected in the question @Ramanlfc

Comment: Since you have JSON objects inside your JSON array, I don't see any way you can access the keys inside directly.

Comment: No, but parsing the JSON in the first place is probably much more costly. Why do you think performance is an issue here?

Comment: Use Map to store id as key and related attributes as values.

Comment: You might get some help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json . But, the question is do you really have that complex require or  just some filtering will do.

Comment: @KislayKishore i wouldn't say its complex but there are about 6000 calls that will happen and that needs to get the position. If we loop it, it takes a lot of time. So just trying to reduce the time taking here.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps stream based parsing ( GSON or similar)  could be an option for determining the index? (https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to re-structure your json like

```
{"results":2,"object":{10:{"pos":1,"rank":12},21:{"pos":2,"rank":22}.........n:{"pos":n,"rank":n}}}
```

Then you can directly fetch it using `object[ur_id].pos`