# Is there JsonPatch analog for filtering json data?

Tags: json, json-patch

I need to construct complex query to json like "field `name` is `Bob` and field `age` less then `40` or `salary` more or equal 40000"

For patch json data I can use JsonPatch, but is there any format for filtering json data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a query language for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json)

Answer (score 1):

JSON Patch is used to perform partial update on json resources.
It seems like you are looking for ways to query a json resource.
For this you can use [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) which is a query language for JSON

I hope this helps anyone.